# What does it return in this function return parent::beforeSave();?

Tags: yii

I don't know what this function will return, just modified record attributes or anything other?

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
    if ($this->getIsNewRecord())
    {
        $this->created = Yii::app()->localtime->UTCNow;
    }             
     $this->lastmodified = Yii::app()->localtime->UTCNow;

     if ($this->dob == '') {
         $this->setAttribute('dob', null);
     } else {
        $this->dob=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->dob));
     }
     if($this->image!="")
     {
        $this->imgfile_name =  $this->image->name;
        $this->imgfile_type =  $this->image->type;
        $this->imgfile_size =  $this->image->size;
     }  
     $this->phone=substr($this->phone,0,3).substr($this->phone,4,3).substr($this->phone,8,4);

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CActiveRecord::beforeSave`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeSave-detail) is supposed to return `true` if the model is in a valid state and can be saved, and `false` if it's not.

Comment: and you need the last line, so that the parent implementation of beforeSave() can fire too